# Xamarin.Forms - How to access /data/user/0/com.companyname.notes/files/.local/share/

Tags: xamarin.forms

I was following a small  [tutorial of Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/single-page?pivots=windows)
Which basically saves your text input onto the internal memory of your device.

```cs
String _filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Notes.txt");
```

Results in: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.notes/files/.local/share/Notes.txt` for me.

Now, while everything works, I would like to see this Notes.txt file in the folder.

I have searched far and wide, but can't seem to find a way to locate this file on my device. 
I can go to *Android/data/com.companyname.notes/files* but then I only see a *._override_* folder with the app project files in it, but without the *Notes.txt*

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is this on an emulator on an actual device?

Comment: On an actual device: a CT60 from Honeywell. (but you got the same thing on an emulator, you can't find it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your path:/data/user/0/com.companyname.notes/files/.local/share/Notes.txt, we can know that you want to access internal storage, but Internal storage refers to the non-volatile memory that Android allocates to the operating system, APKs, and for individual apps. This space is not accessible except by the operating system or apps. So you can not find this text file from internal storage.

If you want to see file, you can save this file in [external storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows)

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files`

More detailed info about internal storage, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

### Update

If you want to save text file, you should declare one of the two permissions for external storage in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then the primary location for private external files is found by calling the method Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(string type). This method will return a Java.IO.File object that represents the private external storage directory for the app. Passing null to this method will return the path to the user's storage directory for the application. As an example, for an application with the package name com.companyname.app, the "root" directory of the private external files would be:

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files/**

In the Forms, you need to create new interface:

```
 public interface IFileSystem
{
    string GetExternalStorage();
}
```

Implement this interface in Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileSystemImplementation))]
```

namespace FileApp.Droid
{
    public class FileSystemImplementation : IFileSystem
    {
        public string GetExternalStorage()
        {
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            var filePath = context.GetExternalFilesDir("");
            return filePath.Path;
        }
    }
}

Now you can create text file and save text in this file:

```
 private async void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var folderPath = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().GetExternalStorage();
        var file = Path.Combine(folderPath, "count.txt");

        using (var writer = File.CreateText(file))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("123456789000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        }
    }
```

I have made a sample:

https://github.com/CherryBu/FileApp

The exact path to the private external storage directory can vary from device to device and between versions of Android.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had the time to test it out, till now.
I'm trying to place it now on the external memory based on your link, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried: Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir()
and Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory but no luck.
Either Content or OS is unknown, or if I remove those, I get the same for the rest of it, like:
'Environment' does not contain a definition for externalstoragedirectory()

Any ideas?

Comment: @GertDeWilde, Please take a look my update and my sample, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  This is great.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your File Manager App
- Go to Android/data
- Find the *.com folder*, in your case, *com.companyname.notes*
- Follow the path until you find the file

Answer (score 0):

I think same type of thing happens with windows too which shows C:\users\user\appdata\local\data.db3 which is sqlite database happens which we can't find there but we can use it thru program